# Terraform - Lost in the Flatten Sequence

Tags: terraform

I have lost the flow of this 'flatten' sequence and need help in ensuring that the traffic manager endpoints are properly represented in the flatten sequence. Although I have gotten to a point where terraform plan works, it is creating the endpoints by Index[0] and Index[1] instead of Indexing it by name.

Below is the code and sample input (in json format). The Azure Traffic Manager profile and Traffic Endpoints (Azure endpoint) exist in the same module.

**Plan Output**

```
  # module.infra.azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint.tm_azure_endpoint["0"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "tm_azure_endpoint" {
      + enabled            = true
      + geo_mappings       = [
          + "US",
        ]
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + name               = "0"
      + priority           = 1
      + profile_id         = "/subscriptions/3f128ee2-eef5-4ede-ac7e-42cf4a4f8632/resourceGroups/rg-eastus-tmprofile/providers/Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/traf-eastus-01"
      + target_resource_id = "/subscriptions/3f128ee2-eef5-4ede-ac7e-42cf4a4f8632/resourceGroups/rg-eastus-tmprofile/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/pip-core-vng-eus-01"
      + weight             = 1
    }

  # module.infra.azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint.tm_azure_endpoint["1"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "tm_azure_endpoint" {
      + enabled            = true
      + geo_mappings       = [
          + "US",
        ]
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + name               = "1"
      + priority           = 1
      + profile_id         = "/subscriptions/3f128ee2-eef5-4ede-ac7e-42cf4a4f8632/resourceGroups/rg-eastus-taf-eastus-01"
      + target_resource_id = (known after apply)
      + weight             = 1
    }
```

**MAIN**

```
locals {
  tm_profile = {
    for k, v in try(local.inputs.tm_profiles, {}) : k => merge(
      {
        existing                     = false
        traffic_view_enabled         = false //optional feature. $2 per million data points processed. Data points are essentially queries into Traffic Manager.
        interval_in_seconds          = 30
        timeout_in_seconds           = 10
        tolerated_number_of_failures = 3
      },
      v,
      {
        tags = merge(
          local.tags,
          try(v.tags, {})
        )
      }
    )
  }
  tmprofile_endpoints = flatten([
    for tm_k, tm_v in try(local.inputs.tm_profiles, {}) : [
      for tm_endpoints_k, tm_endpoints_v in try(tm_v.tm_endpoints, {}) : merge(
        tm_endpoints_v,
        {
          name               = tm_endpoints_k
          profile_id         = azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.traffic_manager_profile[tm_endpoints_v["tm_profile_name"]].id
          target_resource_id = azurerm_public_ip.pub_ips[tm_endpoints_v["pub_ip"]].id
          enabled            = true
          protocol           = tm_v.protocol
        }
      )
    ]
  ])
}

resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_profile" "traffic_manager_profile" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in local.tm_profile : k => v if !v.existing
  }
  name                   = each.key
  resource_group_name    = each.value.rg
  profile_status         = each.value.profile_status
  traffic_routing_method = each.value.traffic_routing_method
  dns_config {
    relative_name = each.value.relative_name
    ttl           = each.value.ttl
  }
  monitor_config {
    protocol                    = each.value.protocol
    port                        = each.value.port
    path                        = (each.value.protocol != "TCP") ? each.value.path : lookup(each.value, "path", null)
    expected_status_code_ranges = try(each.value.expected_status_code_ranges, "200")
    dynamic "custom_header" {
      for_each = (each.value.protocol == "HTTP" || each.value.protocol == "HTTPS") ? try(each.value.custom_headers, {}) : {}
      content {
        name  = each.value.name
        value = each.value.value
      }
    }
    interval_in_seconds          = each.value.interval_in_seconds
    timeout_in_seconds           = each.value.timeout_in_seconds
    tolerated_number_of_failures = each.value.tolerated_number_of_failures
  }
  tags = each.value.tags
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rgs
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "tm_azure_endpoint" {
  for_each = {
  for k, v in local.tmprofile_endpoints : k => v }
  name               = each.key
  profile_id         = each.value.profile_id
  target_resource_id = each.value.target_resource_id
  weight             = each.value.weight
  dynamic "custom_header" {
    for_each = (each.value.protocol == "HTTP" || each.value.protocol == "HTTPS") ? try(each.value.custom_headers, {}) : {}
    content {
      name  = each.value.name
      value = each.value.value
    }
  }
  enabled      = each.value.enabled
  geo_mappings = each.value.geo_mappings
  priority     = each.value.priority
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.traffic_manager_profile
  ]
}
/*
output "tmprofile_endpoints_out" {
  value = local.tmprofile_endpoints
}
*/
```

**Sample Input**

```
"tm_profiles": {
            "traf-eastus-01": {
                "rg": "rg-eastus-tmprofile",
                "profile_status": "Enabled",
                "traffic_routing_method": "Performance",
                "relative_name": "azmech",
                "ttl": 3600,
                "protocol": "HTTPS",
                "port": 443,
                "path": "/",
                "expected_status_code_ranges": [
                    "200-201"
                ],
                "custom_header": {
                    "name": "customheader",
                    "value": null
                },
                "tags": {
                    "tm_profile": "tm_test"
                },
                "tm_endpoints": {
                    "tfendpoint1": {
                        "tm_profile_name": "traf-eastus-01",
                        "weight": "1",
                        "custom_header": {
                            "name": "customheader",
                            "value": null
                        },
                        "geo_mappings": [
                            "US"
                        ],
                        "priority": "1",
                        "pub_ip": "pip-core-vng-eus-01"
                    },
                    "tfendpoint2": {
                        "tm_profile_name": "traf-eastus-01",
                        "weight": "1",
                        "custom_header": {
                            "name": "customheader",
                            "value": null
                        },
                        "geo_mappings": [
                            "US"
                        ],
                        "priority": "1",
                        "pub_ip": "pip-core-vng-wus-01"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to show definition of `azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.traffic_manager_profile` and `azurerm_public_ip.pub_ips`.

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the code and clarified the issue I am having. I was able to make progress on the original issue, but now I seem to be creating the traffic manager endpoints with Index[0] or Index[1] instead of by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice code ;)
If I am getting it right, the flatten causes the indexing. Since flatten works with lists, `local.tmprofile_endpoints` is a list.

I would project it back into a map where each key is unique. You can try to produce a single unique key per instance like this:

```
  local_tmprofile_endpoints_map = {
    for endpoint in local.tmprofile_endpoints : "${endpoint.tm_profile_name}" => endpoint
  }
```

..and work on this from now on.

Comment: Oh of course! Flatten works with lists...completely forgot. I will work with your code and see if I can get this to run.

Comment: that produced a duplicate error. Because ${endpoint.tm_profile_name} has the same value. The tm profile is the same for the endpoints.

Comment: you can combine some other fields into the key, for example "${endpoint.tm_profile_name}.${endpoint.pub_ip}" or use "${endpoint.name}" if I see your merge correctly.

Comment: yep, got it. Changed it to ${endpoint.name}. I think that is correct. Will test it out. Thanks!